# Number of Jordan cells size $j+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could you tell me how to prove that the number of Jordan cells of size $j+1$ is equal to $\dim V^j/V^{j-1}$(quotient space)?

$V^j = \ker (f-\lambda)^j$

I know that for $U_1, U_2, ..., U_s$ - Jordan subspaces of endomorphism $f: X \rightarrow X$ we have $X=U_1\bigoplus U_2\bigoplus ...\bigoplus U_s$

and $\ker (f - \lambda id_X)^p = \ker (f|_{U_1} - \lambda id_{U_1})^p \bigoplus ... \bigoplus \ker (f|_{U_s} - \lambda id_{U_s})^p$.

Can this be useful?

I would appreciate all your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Consider a Jordan form $\Lambda$ of the operator $f$. When you consider the sequence $\{(\Lambda-\lambda I)^j:j\in\mathbb N\}$ of powers, at $j$-th step the rank of each initial Jordan $\lambda$-cell of size $\ge j$ is decreasing by $1$. The sum of all these “1” should be exactly equal to the total decrement of rank, which is equal to $\dim V^j /V^{j−1}$.  Let $n_j$ denotes that the the number of Jordan $\lambda$-cells of size $j$. Then we have

$\dim V^1=n_1+n_2+\dots$

$\dim V^2/V^1=\dim V^2-\dim V^1=n_2+\dots$

$\dots$

So

$n_1=\dim V^1-(\dim V^2-\dim V^1) =2\dim V^1-\dim V^2$.

$n_2=(\dim V^2-\dim V^1)- (\dim V^3-\dim V^2) =2\dim V^2-\dim V^1-\dim V^3$.

$n_3=(\dim V^3-\dim V^2)- (\dim V^4-\dim V^3) =2\dim V^3-\dim V^2-\dim V^4$.

$\dots$

This formulae are different from $n_{j+1}=\dim V^j-\dim V^{j-1}$.  Maybe something is wrong.

Consider an example 
$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right)$

Let $\lambda=2$. Then $n_1=n_4=0$, $n_2=n_3=1$, $\dim V^0=0$, $\dim V^1=2$, $\dim V^2=4$, $\dim V^3=5$, and $\dim V^4=5$.

$n_1=0=2\cdot 2-4=2\dim V^1-\dim V^2$.

$n_2=1=2\cdot 4-2-5=2\dim V^2-\dim V^1-\dim V^3<>\dim V^1/V^0=2$.

$n_3=1=2\cdot 5-4-5=2\dim V^3-\dim V^2-\dim V^4<>\dim V^2/V^1=2$.

Maybe I did an error somewhere.